# Amazon RDS Slow Query Log Does Not Show SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I enabled the slow query log on Amazon RDS and I executed a "select sleep(5)". But when I look at this table, how is it that sql_text does not show the actual SQL statement?

```
mysql> select * from mysql.slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    start_time: 2021-01-27 15:45:08.033183
     user_host: XX
    query_time: 00:00:05.002547
     lock_time: 00:00:00.000000
     rows_sent: 1
 rows_examined: 0
            db: test
last_insert_id: 0
     insert_id: 0
     server_id: 3213123123
      sql_text: 0x73656C65637420736C656570283529
     thread_id: 103213
```

Below are the settings:

```
log_output = TABLE
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = 0
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0
```

What I am not sure is why I got this output:
`sql_text: 0x73656C65637420736C656570283529` which I suspect is the `select sleep(5)` ?

---

Update:

I ran this again to make sure I didn't execute `select HEX(sleep(5))`, and I didn't do that. Also, the sql_text are all the same even though I ran different SQl statements.

```
mysql> select sleep(3);
+----------+
| sleep(3) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.09 sec)

mysql> select * from mysql.slow_log\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    start_time: 2021-01-27 15:45:08.033183
     user_host: XX
    query_time: 00:00:05.002547
     lock_time: 00:00:00.000000
     rows_sent: 1
 rows_examined: 0
            db: 
last_insert_id: 0
     insert_id: 0
     server_id: 1499
      sql_text: 0x73656C65637420736C656570283529
     thread_id: 107032
*************************** 2. row ***************************
    start_time: 2021-01-28 21:26:11.324022
     user_host: XX
    query_time: 00:00:02.000258
     lock_time: 00:00:00.000000
     rows_sent: 1
 rows_examined: 0
            db:
last_insert_id: 0
     insert_id: 0
     server_id: 1499
      sql_text: 0x73656C65637420736C656570283229
     thread_id: 103121
*************************** 3. row ***************************
    start_time: 2021-01-28 21:26:46.160363
     user_host: XX
    query_time: 00:00:03.000205
     lock_time: 00:00:00.000000
     rows_sent: 1
 rows_examined: 0
            db:
last_insert_id: 0
     insert_id: 0
     server_id: 1499
      sql_text: 0x73656C65637420736C656570283329
     thread_id: 110323
3 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

Also, I tested with `log_output = FILE` and I see the correct SQL statements. See below.

```
# Time: 2021-01-28T21:18:10.623686Z
# User@Host: XX Id: 131232
# Query_time: 1.000215 Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1611868690;
select sleep(1);
```

Comment: What is the value of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'long_query_time';` ?

Comment: The value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Check various settings:

```
log_output = TABLE    # versus FILE
slow_query_log = ON
# slow_query_log_file = (fullpath to some file)
long_query_time = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = ON       # optional
log_queries_not_using_indexes = OFF  # optional
```

Comment: I updated the original post to show the settings. What I am not sure is why I got `sql_text: 0x73656C65637420736C656570283529` as the result where I expect to see `select sleep(5)`?

Comment: Sounds like you issued `SELECT HEX("SELECT SLEEP(5)");`

Comment: I updated the original post. It looks like if I use "Table" as log_ouput, I get that weird SQL statement. But using "File" as log_output shows the correct result.

Comment: @BrianEstrada - That `UNHEX(sql_text` will probably give the desired result, but that is a nuisance.  Now that you have a file, consider using `pt-query-digest` to summarize the output.

Comment: Yes, I plan to use "FILE" as the log_output from now on. I am just curious and baffled why I got a "HEX" SQL statement instead of a regular "text-based" SQL statement that I would expect. I don't know what would have caused this.

Comment: @BrianEstrada - Perhaps that is just in case there is a `BLOB` column being dumped.

Comment: Actually, I discovered something! The server is 5.7.31, when I use this version `Ver 8.0.22 for osx10.15 on x86_64`, I get the hex version of the SQL statement. But when I use a MySQL client `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux (x86_64)`, I get the text / normal SQL statement! What is different with 8.0.22???

Comment: @BrianEstrada - A guess:  There may be cases where storing the query as characters (not hex) sometimes causes problems when the charset settings are changed.  Displaying hex avoids such a problem.